# how to calculate amount of COLUMNS containing zero, in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to calculate amount of COLUMNS containing zero, in a multidimensional array.
The number of rows containing zeros I was able to calculate, but I can not understand how to calculate amount of columns. Please, help.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int count = 0;
        int [][] arr = {{3, 0, 0, 6}, {4, 0, 1, 1}};
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the amount of rows containing zeros = " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `break;` from the inner loop and this code will determine the number of columns instead of rows.

Comment: What would prevent columns for being doubled/triple/etc counted if you just removed the break? If `arr[0][0] == 0` and `arr[1][0] == 0`, then count would be 2, even though that's only 1 column, right?

Comment: @JonathanGawrych we'll have to use max of all those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another straightforward way to get the same result for a sqaure matrix:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int i;
        int j;
        int count = 0;
        int [][] arr = {{3, 0, 0, 6}, {4, 0, 1, 0}};

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ", ");} }
                System.out.println();
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------

            for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
                for (j = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
                    if (arr[i][j] == 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
            System.out.println("the amount of rows containing zeros = " + count);

            //--------------------------------------------------------------------
            count=0;

            for (i = 0; i<arr[0].length; i++)
                for (j = 0; j<arr.length; j++)
                    if (arr[j][i] == 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                        break;
                    }
            System.out.println("the amount of cols containing zeros = " + count);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3, 0, 0, 6, 
4, 0, 1, 0, 
the amount of rows containing zeros = 2
the amount of cols containing zeros = 3
```

http://ideone.com/VE0qAw

Comment: Many thanks! Simple and well - perfect, but why did you write that it is suitable for a square matrix?

Comment: the loop would through an out of bounds exception if the matrix isnt sqaure

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not understand, but a square matrix is a matrix in which the number of rows equals the number of columns! My array (matrix) is non-square, but your method still works! I use Google translator, and may not catch some of the subtleties of the translation :) I shared your solution to my question on the Russian version of this site. Thanks again.

Comment: yes correct and it might be because your 1st row has maximum number of elements out of all rows, if your 1st row had more number of elements as compared to other rows, the above code would throw an Exception

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, it's an asymmetrical array.